# Examples of natural transformation-like but doesn't commute?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question

While studying concrete categories (Top, Cat, Grp, Ring, etc), a lot of times I get two functors $F,G: C \to D$ as well as a family of morphisms $\eta_c:Fc \to Gc$. So far, it has never been the case that $\eta$ is not a natural transformation. Given this, it is *very* tempting to not check commutativity of the square.

Mostly to convince myself to actually check the square for future instances, what are some "natural" examples that one could encounter on the wild that seem like natural transformations, but actually aren't? I.e. there are $\eta_c$ but the square doesn't commute.

Answer (score 4):

A standard example is the universal coefficient theorem for homology: given a topological space $X$ and an abelian group $A$, there is a natural short exact sequence
$$
0 \to H_i(X;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes A \to H_i(X;A) \to \mathrm{Tor}(H_{i-1}(X;\mathbb{Z}), A) \to 0.
$$
This splits, but not naturally: there are non-natural isomorphisms
$$
H_i(X;A) \cong H_i(X;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes A \oplus \mathrm{Tor}(H_{i-1}(X;\mathbb{Z}), A).
$$
So take the two sides of this isomorphism to be your two functors.